# Добавление класса на чистом js к нескольким элементам

Tags: javascript

У меня есть 4 элемента:

```
<img onload="imgLoaded()" class='test' src='test'>
<img onload="imgLoaded()" class='test' src='test'>
<img onload="imgLoaded()" class='test' src='test'>
<img onload="imgLoaded()" class='test' src='test'>
```

При вызове функции `imgLoaded`, мне надо добавить ко всем 4 элементам класс `'loaded';`

Как это можно сделать на чистом js ?

```
function imgLoaded(){
 var img = document.getElementsByClassName('test'); 
 img.classList.add("loaded");
};
```

Получаю ошибку:

> ```
>  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
>      at imgLoaded
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
[...document.getElementsByClassName('test')].forEach(i => i.classList.add("loaded"));
```